# #if(DEBUG) and log4net line number source/runtime mismatch

Tags: c#, logging, c-preprocessor, log4net, preprocessor-directive

When I use preprocessor directives like

```
1 #if(DEBUG)
2 // 1
3 // 2
4 #else
5 // 1
6 // 2
7 #endif
8
9 logger.Debug("Log exception, etc.");
```

it causes that at runtime the line numbers in the log (eg. stack trace) are incorrect - in the above example line 9 would become 4 because the rest would be parsed by the preprocessor.

It makes log analysis quite difficult.

**Is there a way to solve this issue without creating methods with `ConditionalAttribute`?**

I'm aware of `Debugger.IsAttached` (and I'm using this solution now) but I would prefer to run code based on the build mode (debug/release) not on whether the debugger is attached.

Comment: I write C# code like this all the time, and when I `logger.Debug("Exception:" + exception)`, the line numbers in the exception trace come out correct - they match the original source file.  I suspect something else is wrong.  Give us a real example, not one like this that wouldn't actually throw an exception.

Comment: I checked again in a completely separate project and you're right, the exception trace is correct. Unfortunately I already refactored my (large) project with Debugger.IsAttached and the problem went away so I (groundlessly as it turns out) suspected that preprocessor directives were the issue. Maybe the .pdb were not in sync with the binaries. Since I'm unable to reproduce the issue now I consider it solved. Thanks for the comment. It's good to know that this scenario is supported.

Comment: Please copy your comment an as answer and accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I checked again in a completely separate project and as [Ross Patterson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/241753/ross-patterson) suggests, the exception trace is correct.

Unfortunately I already refactored my (large) project with Debugger.IsAttached and the problem went away so I (groundlessly as it turns out) suspected that preprocessor directives were the issue. Maybe the .pdb were not in sync with the binaries.

Since I'm unable to reproduce the issue now I consider it solved. It's good to know that this scenario is supported. Thanks [Ross Patterson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/241753/ross-patterson)!